# How do I change the installation path in an OS X installer built with pkgbuild/productbuild?

Tags: javascript, macos, pkgbuild, productbuild, installation-path

We have an application which installs to a custom folder and now we have to create an installer for an application extension (plugin).
The installer of the host application was created with a cross-platform tool, which permits the user to choose the installation folder and even it permits to install multiple versions on the same system.
The host application is not just an "app", as in case of many Mac programs, but a directory which contains several files + an "app".

The plugin installer should:
 1. be pkgbuild/productbuild based, because we doesn't want to use cross-platform installer because it is Java based and we had troubles with it
 2. query all installed host applications with CFBundleIdentifier and choose one to install
 3. **install the content of the payload to the directory of the chosen host application**

I managed to find solutions for the first two requirements, but I don't know how to proceed with the third.
**Is there any solution to change the installation path from the Distribution.xml?**
I played with choice.customLocation attribute, but I didn't managed to modify from JavaScript.

Is there any "elegant" solution for it?

Thanks.